# Laravel custom pagination view not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream

I'm using Laravel 8 with Tailwind CSS. Tried customising the default pagination view as per documentation. Published the view using `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`, but it is still using the default, not the published view. I also tried explicitly specifying the default view for paginator as described in the documentation, by adding
`Paginator::defaultView('resources/views/vendor/pagination/tailwind.blade.php');` to AppServiceProvider:boot() method. That also doesn't work. Clearing caches didn't help.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out because I was using Livewire component for rendering the page, had to use `php artisan livewire:publish --pagination` instead. Which publishes the exact same file, but into `livewire` instead of `pagination` subdirectory. Which is super confusing IMHO and should be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the punctualization. I agree it should be in the docs.

Comment: See https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination#custom-pagination-view for more information.